# Триггер не распознает игрока

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Я установил галочку Is trigger на MonkeTrigger и галочку BananaTrigger, BananaTrigger работает и банан успешно поднимается , а вот MonkeTrigger не работает

MonkeyInteract.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class MonkeInteract : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject trigger;   //MonkeTrigger

    
    public BananaPickUp BananaPickUps; // Импорт переменной Banana из скрипта BananaPickUp

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        
        if( BananaPickUps.Banana == 1 && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))//При условии что игрок находится в MonkeTrigger и нажимает на Е переменная Banan = 0 
        {

            BananaPickUps.Banana = 0;
            Debug.Log(BananaPickUps.Banana);// Проверка работы триггера MonkeTrigger он не работает
        }

        


        }


    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(BananaPickUps.Banana); // Проверка импорта переменной из BananaPickUp, она работает и при запуске показывает что Banana = 0 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

BananaPickUp.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine



    public GameObject trigger;// BananaTrigger
    public GameObject item;//Banana


    public int Banana = 0;//Изначально перeменная Banana 0
    bool pickup = false;


private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        pickup = true;
        

        if (pickup == true && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))// при этом условии Banana = 1
        {


            item.SetActive(false);

            Banana = 1;
            Debug.Log(Banana);
            

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[docs.unity3d Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html)

> Note also that the Input flags are not reset until Update. It is suggested you make all the Input calls in the Update Loop.

---

> Также обратите внимание, что флаги ввода не сбрасываются до обновления. Предлагается выполнять все входные вызовы в цикле обновления.

У обновлений кадра (`Update`/`LateUpdate`) и обновлений физики разный такт.

Comment: Возможно, но проблема была в том что я просто был не внимателен и не поставил галочку MonkeTrigger: Box Collider. Спасибо за поддержку!

Answer (score 0):

У меня скрипт работает идеально, просто надо было поставить галочку на MonkeTrigger Box Collider и поставить галочку на параметре Is Trigger! Если у кого произошла такая же проблема и скрипт работает без ошибок просто пересмотрите параметры вашего триггера.